# Encrypted XML deserialization can't convert to the proper object

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I'm currently trying to build an encrypted serializer class. The goal is to encrypt an xml serialized class for user settings, or any other class that needs to be saved.

The unencrypted version of the serializer works fine, and allows the user to change and save settings.
The encrypted version works when all the settings are left as default. It can serialize and deserialize from an encrypted file. **However, as soon as the settings are changed at runtime and resaved, the deserialization when re-opening gives "There is an error in XML Document (19,12).**

> Message='', hexadecimal value 0x04, is an invalid character. Line 19,
>   position 12.
>          Source=System.Xml

The problem seems to be in the deserialization logic. The XmlSerializer needs a type to deserialize to... but on Reading a file, I only have the default "blank" type. In my head, this seems like it shouldn't have been a problem, because the structure of the class doesn't change, only the actual members' values... and it worked when things weren't encrypted, and even a bit when encrypted. However, I haven't managed to implement this with encryption for some reason.

What's strange is that the not-encrypted version works fine, but the encryption system also seems to work, except it's messing with something... like Byte[] lengths or something.

```
    public dynamic Read()
    {
        dynamic data = Activator.CreateInstance(dataType.GetType()); //dataType is brought in from constructor, see below
        try
        {
            ObjectXmlSerializer oxs = new ObjectXmlSerializer();
            Byte[] fileBytes;
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open)) 
            {
                fileBytes = AesDecrypt(ReadToEnd(fs), key);
            }
            data = oxs.Deserialize<dynamic>(fileBytes,dataType);
            return data;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Error in deserialization");
        }
    }
```

Deserialization happens here. To get the type to properly return bObj's type, I got to bringing in a sample objType... however this seems to be causing an issue.

```
public T Deserialize<T>(Byte[] bObj,T objType)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bObj))
    {
        return (T)new XmlSerializer(objType.GetType()).Deserialize(ms);
    }
}
```

Functions in Settings class that loads/saves existing settings

```
public static Settings LoadSettings()
    {
        Settings newSettings = new Settings();
        EncryptedSerializer serializer = new EncryptedSerializer(path, newSettings, Settings.key);
        //Serializer serializer = new Serializer(path, newSettings);
        // check if settings were already loaded, if so read them.
        // otherwise, if it's a new file, then write the defaults to it
        if (new FileInfo(path).Length > 0)
        {
            newSettings = serializer.Read();
        }
        else
        {
            // save default user settings to file
            serializer.Write();
        }
        return newSettings;
    }

public static void SaveSettings(Settings settings)
{
    EncryptedSerializer serializer = new EncryptedSerializer(path, settings, Settings.key);
    //Serializer serializer = new Serializer(path, settings);
    serializer.Write();
}
```

}

Thanks a bunch for any help
edit: aesdecrypt() code

```
public static Byte[] AesDecrypt(Byte[] src,Key key)
{
    using (RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        try
        {
            myRijndael.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            myRijndael.Key = key.keyBytes;
            myRijndael.IV = key.initVectorBytes;
            myRijndael.Padding = key.paddingMode;

            using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = myRijndael.CreateDecryptor())
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    csDecrypt.Write(src, 0, src.Length);
                    csDecrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
                }
                myRijndael.Clear();
                return msDecrypt.ToArray();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Error in decryption");
        }
        //finally
        //{
        //    //myRijndael.Clear();
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: 99% of the time your problem is improper decryption. please show the code for `AesDecrypt`

Comment: Hi Scott. I've added the AesDecrypt() code. Originally I didn't put it in since the decryption works fine when the object that gives the deserializer its type is the same as what's in the file.